# Including colon [:] in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement where one of my field should accept the value in format 1:2:3:4 and so on. I have written the pattern "[0-9]+(:?[0-9]+?)". if input is 1:2 then it works fine but if it is like 1:2:3 it doesnt matches the pattern an throw me an error.

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1:2:3";
    System.out.println(s.matches("\\d+(:\\d+)*")); // matches single digit followed by 0 or more :[digit]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern: `[0-9]+(:?[0-9]+?)` means: one or more digits, optionally followed by a `:`, optionally followed by one or more digits.

An input like `1:2:3` obviously doesn't match this - your regex does not say that you can have another `:` after the second digits.

If you want to accept an arbitrary number of groups separated by `:`, then put a `*` (which means: zero or more times) after the group. And remove the `?` after the `:` and the second group of digits:

`[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)*`

This means: one or more digits, followed by zero or more times: a colon, optionally followed by one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d+(:\d+)*$
```

For using in Java pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+(:\\d+)*$");
```

Comment: `/.../` is not Java regex syntax. Also, `^` and `$` are redundant if you use `matches`.